# passing a tuple in function

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I went through questions but I couldn't figure it out in case of mine

I wrote a function which takes a tuple as a parameter and performs this:

```
def add_subject(name_stud, *data):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO " + name_stud + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
             data)
    conn.commit()
```

And I tried calling this function in a class method passing tuple as a parameter but I get error

```
add_subject(self.page1.student_name, data)
```

data is the tuple there.

and the error is:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 1 supplied.

And I tried unpacking at the time I am using it, I still got error:

```
def add_subject(name_stud, data):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO " + name_stud + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
              *data)
    conn.commit()
```

error:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answers from other peoples didn't help me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `data`?

Comment: Have you tried it without unpacking anywhere? IIRC you don't need to unpack in execute

Comment: yes i tried but still the error is sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing the tuple as a single argument, you shouldn't write `*data` in the function definition. Just declare it as an ordinary function parameter.

```
def add_subject(name_stud, data):
    row = data
    c.execute("INSERT INTO " + name_stud + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", 
             data)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I thought that too but I get error: 
> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the table columns and the values in the tuple?

Answer (score 2):

You've declared the parameter `data` as positional args, but are passing only a single argument, `data`. This means that the final parameter will be `(data,)`. You need to unpack the tuple on passing in order to populate the positional args.

```
add_subject(self.page1.student_name, *data)
```

Comment: but still that will give me
    TypeError: add_subject() takes 2 positional arguments but 9 were given

Comment: Not with how you've defined it. The signature takes 1 to 255 arguments.